# Monitoring webpage load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I am trying to see which javascript functions are changing some elements of a webpage when its loading.

I can monitor which javascript function is making changes to an element after the webpage loads using Firebug.

But, if I already know which elements of the webpage or which cookie changes I want to monitor, is there any way to monitor them when the page loads? Not the changes after the page has loaded.

Even if there was some way to know which javascripts are making the changes, that would also help. The pages I am trying to monitor are loading a lot of javascripts.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to monitor it using F12 -> Network then refresh page. From there get links of all js and go through their source you will get quick idea. As which one relates to which one. Hope it might help you :)

Comment: The pages I am trying to load, loads over 20 javascript each of them being over 2000 lines when properly formatted. I did do what you were saying when I was doing this first. But there a lot of pages I have to do this for. And I was basically searching for document.cookie in those JS and then tracing back to who called those functions. But even then there were too many. Not all of them were actually creating cookies. But they were there to handle different cases. And searching for changes in webpage elements is even more painful.